# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "как"?

Tags: пунктуация

Многие западные инвесторы выходят из проектов Российского арктического шельфа
и пр., как неадекватных текущей экономической ситуации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая нужна обязательно, так как конструкция с союзом КАК имеет **значение причины**. Ср.: ***Многие западные инвесторы выходят из проектов Российского арктического шельфа и пр., так как эти проекты неадекватны текущей экономической ситуации.***

Answer (score 2):

Да, запятая нужна, но интересно разобрать грамматику.

Фактически  здесь не приложение, а определительный оборот после определяемого слова, которому союз КАК придает причинное значение.

Сравнить: Многие западные инвесторы выходят из проектов Российского арктического шельфа и пр., неадекватных текущей экономической ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, здесь не нужна. Тут как раз классический пример союза "как" в значении "в качестве". Но, честно говоря, я бы предложение переформулировала - не сразу получается уловить, к чему относится вторая часть предложение. Лучше написать, что "инвесторы выходят из проектов, поскольку те (но не "они", а то можно будет подумать, что неадекватны инвесторы) не адекватны экономической ситуации" (ну и пусть выходят, Россия сама должна учиться работать!).

Answer (score 0):

Ставим обязательно запятую: причинное отношение 
... поскольку эти проекты ...
Следовательно, полностью поддерживаю 3-й ответ.